# Sql select and display all values of one column after grouping by other column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table that stores the score of each driver and the team he is racing for.

```
driver    team     points
-------------------------
Josh      Mercedes   12
Aron      BMW         5
Ben       Mercedes    9
Jake      BMW        17
Mike      BMW         7
Brad      Chevrolet   3
```

Now I'd like to display the score for each team + the names of all drivers in the team.

**The desired output:**

```
BMW         29     Aron, Jake, Mike
Mercedes    21     Josh, Ben
Chevrolet    3     Brad
```

**Query:**
The problem with my query is that it only displays the first driver's name. What function do I have to use to include the names of all the drivers?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT driver, team, points, SUM(points) AS totals FROM `example-table` GROUP BY team ORDER BY `points` DESC";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount())
{
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

echo $result['team'];
echo $result['driver'];
echo $result['totals'];
?>
<br>

<?php 
}// end while
}// end if
else {
 echo '0 results';
}// end else
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Group_Concat](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) function

```
SELECT team, SUM(points) AS totals,group_concat(driver)
FROM `example-table` 
GROUP BY team 
ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!