# Grouping by one column, aggregating with a second column, displaying other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I guess I wish I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855605/8837045) but for SQL Server.

I have a table `records` with columns `name`, `last_modified`, and then `month` and `price`.

I'd like to group by `name` and aggregate with `MAX(last_modified)`, but I also want to display the `month` and `price` corresponding to the row selected (by the MAX() function). I don't want to group by `month` and `price` because these can vary too, but at the same time I can't put them in the select without including them in the group by clause.

Right now I'm trying to come up with something like this :

```
SELECT name, last_modified, month, price
FROM schema.records 
WHERE (name, last_modified) IN 
(
    SELECT name, MAX(last_modified)
    FROM schema.records 
    WHERE month='JANUARY'
    GROUP BY name
)
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: what is wrong with your query?

Comment: `string_agg()` can work similar to group_concat(), but group_concat() wouldn't help this very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for this

```
select name, max(last_modified) over(partition by name) last_modified, 
   month,
   price
from schema.records
where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT r.name, r.last_modified, r.month, r.price
FROM schema.records r
WHERE r.last_modified = (SELECT name, MAX(r2.last_modified)
                         FROM schema.records r2
                         WHERE r2.month = 'JANUARY' AND r2.name = r.name
                        );
```

Comment: This is probably fine, but I worry it might be possible to have two items with the same last_modified, especially if the time values for the column are all zeroed out.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn . . . This is based on he desired query described by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to do this as below -

```
Select
    name,
    month,
    Price,
    Last_modified
From
    (SELECT 
          name, 
          month,
          price,
          last_modified,
          row_number() over(partition by name order by last_modified desc) as seq_num
          FROM schema.records 
         WHERE month= 'JANUARY') T
 where T.seq_num = 1;
```

Also, in your question you expressed a wish if something like MySQL group_concat can be done in SQL Server. Well, actually it can be done. Please refer below.

```
SELECT 
          name, 
          max(last_modified),
          array_to_string(array_agg(month), ',') as month_list,
          array_to_string(array_agg(price), ',') as price_list
          FROM schema.records 
         WHERE month= 'JANUARY'
       Group by name;
```